# wy in DB table is not creating and showing this errors invalid foreignKey in Django

Tags: python, django

> wy in DB table is not creating and showing this errors invalid foreignKey
> .IntegrityError: The row in table 'myecomapp_toplist' with primary key '2' has an invalid foreign key: myecomapp_toplist.subcategory_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in myecomapp_subcategory.id.
> `models.py`

```
class TopList(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProductImg')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    discountpercentage = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    discountPrice = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    brandName = models.TextField(max_length = 100 , default='',null=True,blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000 ,null=True,blank=True)
    finalprice = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory , on_delete=models.CASCADE , default=1)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(subcategory , on_delete=models.CASCADE , default=1)


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_categories():
        return ProductCategory.objects.all()


    def __str__(self):
        representtion of this model object
        return self.name

class subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    MainCategory = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory , on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(subcategory)
class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
 


@admin.register(FirstSliderData)
class FirstsliderModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['id','image','title' ,'category']

@admin.register(TopList)
class TodoListModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['id','image','title' ,'category']
```

Comment: You have kept a default value for the subcategory and category foreign keys in the TopList model. Here SubCategory has no object with a pk 1 causing the Foreign Key constraint to fail.

Comment: it is also showing same error when i remove `default = 1`

Comment: It is because the instance of TopList already exists in the db with a value 1. You will have to delete the entry or modify it to a value that actually exists.

Comment: when i add  ,`null=True ,blank=True`    on TopList it work fine